# How do I obtain only digits from a string?

Tags: shell, grep, solaris

Suppose I have a string like this:

`blah=-Xms512m`

I want the output as `512`.

I know I can get it using `grep` on Linux like this:
`echo $blah | grep -o -e [0-9]\\+`
But this doesn't work on `Solaris`.

Any nice solutions so that it's compatible on both, Linux and Solaris?
Or atleast on Solaris?

Comment: The problem is not that it doesn't work "on Solaris", the problem is (probably) that the grep you are using on Solaris doesn't support -o.  But grep is the wrong tool for this.  Use tr.

Comment: I agree. That's what I wanted to mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I f you know the numbers will be together like that:

```
pax> echo 'blah=-Xms512m' | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'
512
```

It basically replaces all non-numeric characters with nothing. Of course, it won't do sensible stuff with:

```
pax> echo 'blah77=-Xms512m' | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'
77512
```

but, if you've only got one number it will work fine.

If you just need the first number, you can use:

```
pax> echo 'blah77=-Xms512m' | sed -e 's/^[^0-9]*//' -e 's/[^0-9].*$//'
77
```

For the last:

```
pax> echo 'blah77=-Xms512m' | sed -e 's/[^0-9]*$//' -e 's/^.*[^0-9]//'
512
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be completly brute-force, try using tr:

```
echo "blah=-Xms512m" | tr -c -d '[0-9]'
```